# Symmetrical tree traversal

Tags: graph, tree, tree-traversal

[image]

I have a tree. Help me specify the order of nodes when traversing a tree symmetrically, please.

I think so, but I doubt: `11, 5, 12, 13, 3, 6, 2, 7, 4, 14, 8, 9, 16, 15, 10`

Comment: What is your definition of "symmetrical traversal"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This graph isn't a binary tree, so symmetric traversal is not possible.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).